# IllegalStateException while begin transaction for Fragment

Tags: android

After getting success or failure response from Retrofit, I am displaying a alert dialog. Alert dialog class is extending DialogFragment.

Before displaying dialog if I click home button, then my app crashes.

I have searched  and tried below but that doesn't helped me.

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        isTransactionSafe = true;
        if(isTransactionPending)
            showDialog(alertDialog);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        isTransactionSafe = true;
    }



    public void showDialog(UpdateAlertDialog updateAlertDialog) {


        // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
        // in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
        // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
        alertDialog=updateAlertDialog;
        if (isTransactionSafe) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
            if (prev != null) {
                ft.remove(prev);
            }
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            // Create and show the dialog.
            updateAlertDialog.show(ft, "dialog");
            isTransactionPending=false;
        }
        else{
            isTransactionPending=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my stack trace,

```
  Process: com.nexge.zalcon, PID: 17629
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1536)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1558)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:317)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:172)
        at com.nexge.zalcon.activity.DetailsRecyclerView.showDialog(DetailsRecyclerView.java:400)
        at com.nexge.zalcon.activity.DetailsRecyclerView$2.onResponse(DetailsRecyclerView.java:349)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:83)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Anybody help me to solve this...

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: You set isTransactionSafe = true; in onPause, may be it's the problem

Comment: @Bracadabra that's the issue...tq now its working fine

Comment: Great, then I copy the comment to answer the question and don;t leave it alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is wrong assignment in onPause, just set isTransactionSafe to false:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    isTransactionSafe = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should check

```
if (getActivity() != null && isAdded())
```

before displaying the dialog

Comment: it doesn't helped me... Im calling showDialog() in Activity that extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: @Christopher I have  added stack trace

Comment: in your dialogFragment override show method and add this inside 
`FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(this, tag);
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();`

Comment: I have searched about commitAllowingStateLoss. It is not better to use it...It seems like a quick fix...but I wanted to fix it properly

Comment: then probably you should read [this](https://medium.com/@elye.project/handling-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-d4ee8b630066)

Comment: the link u given is not opening...getting 404

Comment: https://medium.com/@elye.project/handling-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-d4ee8b630066